# What functionality does Hive have that impala does not? Hive vs Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera, impala

I have used HIVE 13.1 extensively and want to start running some of my jobs in Impala 2.5.  What functionalities in current hive are not available in impala?  Has anyone transitioned workflows from Hive to Impala, what are things to look out for?

Comment: DATE and DECIMAL data types. Some ALTER commands *(but you can run these in a Hive shell anyway)*. The fact that Hive always checks for new files in an EXTERNAL table, while Impala keeps file&block location in a cache so that you must force a cache refresh before each query.

Comment: And of course no support for ORC, AVRO, etc. (Parquet all the things!)

Comment: No real control on the number of files created by an INSERT command *(in Hive you can throttle the # of Reducers and  tweak "merge.smallfiles" properties)*.

Comment: In other words, with Impala, everything that's not mandatory is *de facto* forbidden. On the other hand, it's really fast. And sometimes entertaining, when you find a specific SQL syntax that crashes a daemon with SEGV signal and core dump...

Comment: Avro (+ RCFile, SequenceFile, Parquet, text) and DECIMAL are supported now, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the issue here pertains to "functionality differences" per se but rather, use case.

If your use case involves long-running ETL jobs run by a single user (and hence fault tolerance is the main requirement), Impala will offer few advantages over Hive.

If your use case involves multiple users writing concurrent BI-style queries for doing analytics (and hence low latency is the main requirement), Impala will always be faster than Hive.

So, there's plenty of room for both.